# About a compact imbedding of Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators

I am studying the Compactness lemma ( on page 570) of the article http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103922134.

The lemma says

(Compactness lemma ): for $0 < \sigma < \frac{2}{N-2}$, $(N \geq 3)$, the  imbedding

$$ H^{1}_{rad}(R^n) \rightarrow L^{2 \sigma +2} (R^n)$$
is compact, where $H^{1}_{rad}(R^n)$ is the radial functions of $H^{1}(R^n)$.

Proof of the lemma:

Consider the interpolation estimate

$$ || u ||^{2 \sigma +2}_{2 \sigma +2} \leq C || u||^{\sigma N}_{H^{1}(R^n)} || u||_{L^2(R^n)}^{2 + \sigma(2-N)} , 0 < \sigma < \frac{2}{N-2} $$

(this is the classical Gagliardo - Nirenberg - Sobolev inequality ).

If we can show that a bounded sequence in $H^{1}_{rad}(R^n)$ is uniformly small at infinity , then follows the result (*).

This uniformity follows from the inequality

$$|u(x)| \leq \frac{C}{|x|^{\frac{N-1}{2}}} || u||_{H^1}  (**)$$

The inequality of $(**)$ is given in a article. But i am not understanding the affirmation of $(*)$
Someone can help me to understand?

thanks in advance

Comment: Rather amusing how many people well aware of the embedding's $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ not being compact, are surprised to find out the embedding $H_{rad}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be compact $\,\forall\,p\in [2,\frac{2n}{n-2})$ when $n\geqslant 3$, and $\,\forall\,p\in [2,\infty)$ when $n=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to establish that any sequence $\,u_k=u_k(|x|)\to 0\,$ weakly convergent in $\,H_{rad}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\,$ will be srongly convergent in $\,L^{2\sigma+2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which might be ruined by the unboundedness of $\,\mathbb{R}^n$ if it were not for the remarkable inequality $\,(\ast\ast)\,$ that provides cutting off the infinity.  Indeed, given any $\varepsilon >0$, choose $R_{\varepsilon}>1$ such that
$$
\int\limits_{|x|>R_{\varepsilon}}\Bigl|u_k(|x|)\Bigr|^{2\sigma+2}dx\leqslant \Biggl(\int\limits_{\,\,|x|>R_{\varepsilon}}\Bigl|u_k(|x|)\Bigr|^{2}dx\Biggr)\!\cdot\!\Biggl(\frac{\|u_k\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}}{R_{\varepsilon}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}\Biggr)^{\!2\sigma}\!
\leqslant\\ \leqslant R_{\varepsilon}^{-\sigma (n-1)}\!\!\cdot\!\Bigl(\sup\limits_{k\geqslant 1}\|u_k\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}\Bigr)^{2\sigma+2}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
\quad \forall\, k\geqslant 1,
$$
and notice that there is $\,m_{\varepsilon}\in \mathbb{N}\,$ such that
$$
\int\limits_{|x|<R_{\varepsilon}}\Bigl|u_k(|x|)\Bigr|^{2\sigma+2}dx
<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \quad \forall\, k>m_{\varepsilon}
$$ 
due to the compact embedding $\,H^1(B_{R_{\varepsilon}})\hookrightarrow
L^{2\sigma+2}(B_{R_{\varepsilon}})\,$ for a ball $\,B_{R_{\varepsilon}}=
\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,\colon\,|x|<R_{\varepsilon}\} $.

Comment: the compact immersion that you used is the rellich kondrashov immersion ?

Comment: @Leandro Tavares: Yes, for a ball $B_{R_{\varepsilon}}$ it is the theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem

Comment: thank you for answer my questions!